# Android masking background with round gradient shape

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to implement following component, but not sure where to start.

I have two fragments stacked. Top fragment has gradient background and other content as well. Fragment below that has also own content and you should be able to see below content.

Following picture demonstrates the situation and the white round should be movable, so user can see below content on certain position.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the solution from Romain Guy. As far as I know this is the simplest (and possibly most efficient method since *he* recommended it). The solution is based on `Shader`s.

You can find code, description, whole project, sample video and screenshots here: http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/13/android-recipe-2-fun-with-shaders/

You would start your customization by adjusting the mask PNG file. Then you'd probably supply a shader parameter for the fragments which they would utilize when drawing. Finally you'd set the proper shader for each of the fragments after every pointer movement event.

I know it's just a sketch of the solution, but the whole project code provided in the link above should get you going really fast.

Comment: I'm having difficulties using that approach, since it needs the bottom view for the masking. Is it possible to use like a black round png and revert it white and use some xfermode in paint to get it working?

Comment: what do you mean by "needs the bottom view for masking"? I think it doesn't. the `SpotlightView` will mask anything that is in `mTargetBitmap`. I would probably create a `ViewGroup` which would do the job of `SpotlightView` but for all children views. it would override `onDraw()` and draw them to the `mTargetBitmap`. *then* it would use this bitmap pixels as the mask target and apply the mask. this is similar to what `SlidingDrawer` does - except we're masking and SD is clipping - this is seen in the `SlidingDrawer.dispatchDraw()`.

Comment: But if the spotlight needs to move fast, doesn't that cost performance because it needs new targetBitmap all the time? Or is it suppost to have full view as target bitmap and crop that?

Comment: that would be costly, but you don't have to recreate this bitmap every time. you can allocate it once and just modify it in subsequent draw calls. this is already in the framework - when you start masking call `target.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)`. when you need to get the target bitmap just call `target.getDrawingCache()` - the target will allocate or modify the bitmap for you. when you're done call `target.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false)`.

Comment: I was thinking if it possible to just get it work that the top `Fragment` has black background and you could see through the white round and the top layer doesn't know anything about the below content.

Comment: yeah, I think this will work, but it will still need the top fragment to be drawn to a offscreen bitmap which will then be drawn to the canvas using a mask.

Comment: Got it working with the link provided way, no performance issues because the transformation of matrix is fast.