# displaying google map as a circle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps

I am using a GoogleMapSupport fragment in the xml view of one of my activities.  The fragment is just 150x150dip square currently in the corner of my view.  I was wondering if there is an efficient way to MASK the map fragment so that it appears as circle instead of a a square.  I have looked aroud and found this post : [Android masking background with round gradient shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830930/android-masking-background-with-round-gradient-shape)

But That seems to be an example using canvas and the view i want to actually mask is a MapSupportFragment..  below is an image showing what i'd like to achieve if at all possible and my current xml layout.

[image]

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/arFrame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewLocation"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:text="no signal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<com.KingNozzle.Views.KNMultiDirectionalSlidingDrawer
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.KingNozzle"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    my:content="@+id/content"
    my:direction="topToBottom"
    my:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <include
        android:id="@id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        layout="@layout/empty_rel" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:src="@drawable/sliding_drawer_handle_bottom" />
</com.KingNozzle.Views.KNMultiDirectionalSlidingDrawer>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply add an overlay?

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but maybe you could use Google Static Maps API. Get the images and display it in a rounded-shape button or view.